# How to get the csv file from a POST call using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, csv

I am trying to update the database using the CSV file. I have created an API call and whenever I call the API the CSV data will get uploaded to the database. Right now I have given the path to the CSV file which is like `let stream = fs.createReadStream("DATA_May2020.csv");` but instead of hardcoding I want to fetch the CSV file from the API POST call I am making and pass that CSV file to `fs.createReadStreaam`

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Below is my route call to my main method

```
router.post("/uploadcsv", tenant_check, function(req , res){
    main();
    res.status(200).send("data uploaded successfully");
    res.end();
});
```

below is the main method I am using to create a Table

```
async function main(){
    
    const table = new sql.Table('[dbo].[Data1]');
    table.create = true;
    table.columns.add('ID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Name', sql.VarChar, { length: 500, nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Lng', sql.Float, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Lat', sql.Float, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Radius', sql.VarChar, { length: 50, nullable: true })

    try {
        let stream = fs.createReadStream("DATA_May2020.csv");
        let csvStream = fastcsv
        .parse(
            {
                "headers": true,
                "delimiter": ";"
            }
        )
        .on("data", function(data) {      
            table.rows.add(
                data['ID'],
                data['Name'],
                data['Lng'],
                data['Lat'],
                data['Radius']                
            );            
        })
        .on("end", async function() {
            console.log(`Parsed ${table.rows.length} messages, now inserting to SQL..`);
            create_sql_table(table, cleanup);
            //console.log(table);
           
        });

        stream.pipe(csvStream);
 
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
```

}

and below is my code for uploading the data into the created table

```
async function create_sql_table(table, callback) {
    await pool1Connect; // ensures that the pool has been created
    return pool1Connect.then((pool) => {
        pool.request().bulk(table, (err, result) => {
            // ... error checks
            
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error while inserting to database :- " + err);                
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log("Table created OK...");                

            }
            callback();
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        // ... error handler
        console.log("Error connecting to pool: ");
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @Brettski I have edited my code as per your request